# Is Google Cloud Endpoints going to replace the ProtoRPC API?

Tags: google-app-engine, protorpc, google-cloud-endpoints

Just watched the endpoints demo in google I/O 2012 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU_wNR_UUn4 and also http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/).

If I understood correctly this replaces the functionality offered by ProtoRPC API, as well as providing an automatic way to prepare the client side API endpoint.

Since this can affect my decision of using ProtoRPC in a future project, does anybody knows whether Endpoints is going to replace ProtoRPC or not?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python implementation of Endpoints is built on ProtoRPC. Rather than thinking of it as a replacement, I would consider it a supplement.

Comment: So would a code that was written for protoRPC undergo changes? For example would there be any use for the Message class?

Comment: The Message classes are still useful. They define the inputs and response formats of your Endpoints.